# Getting a dependency graph/tree for .Net where the referenced dlls are NOT within the same solution

Tags: .net, dependencies

As the title says, what's the best way of getting a dependency graph/tree for .Net where the refernenced dlls do NOT reside within the same solution?

The VS2010 Architecture-> Generate Dependency Graph seems to only pick up references to projects within the same solution - and a few of the 'system' Dlls.

I'd really like to see the full tree all the way down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out [ndepend](http://www.ndepend.com/)